# Traceback Errors in Ansible (Python version mismatch?)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ansible

I am getting a traceback error when I run the following

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts fmg-playbooks/01_add_model_device.yml
```

I am running Ansible 2.9 and Python 3.6.5

```
ansible 2.9.11
  config file = /home/alice/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/alice/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.5 (default, Apr  1 2018, 05:46:30) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

I get a warning about Python version

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[DEPRECATION WARNING]: Distribution Ubuntu 18.04 on host fmg01 should use /usr/bin/python3, but is using /usr/bin/python for backward compatibility with prior Ansible releases. A future Ansible release
will default to using the discovered platform python for this host. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/reference_appendices/interpreter_discovery.html for more information. This feature will be
removed in version 2.12. Deprecation warnings can be disabled by setting deprecation_warnings=False in ansible.cfg.
ok: [fmg01]
```

And then when I try to add the device, I get a traceback error

```
TASK [Add model device] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: Method not found
fatal: [fmg01]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/alice/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-123199visyis5f/ansible-tmp-1598231721.9686775-123291-130397920449540/AnsiballZ_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 102, in <module>\n    _ansiballz_main()\n  File \"/home/alice/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-123199visyis5f/ansible-tmp-1598231721.9686775-123291-130397920449540/AnsiballZ_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 94, in _ansiballz_main\n    invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)\n  File \"/home/alice/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-123199visyis5f/ansible-tmp-1598231721.9686775-123291-130397920449540/AnsiballZ_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 40, in invoke_module\n    runpy.run_module(mod_name='ansible_collections.fortinet.fortimanager.plugins.modules.fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device', init_globals=None, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 188, in run_module\n    fname, loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 82, in _run_module_code\n    mod_name, mod_fname, mod_loader, pkg_name)\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py\", line 72, in _run_code\n    exec code in run_globals\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_3LmHxl/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/modules/fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 362, in <module>\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_3LmHxl/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/modules/fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device.py\", line 345, in main\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_3LmHxl/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/module_utils/fortimanager.py\", line 62, in __init__\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_3LmHxl/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible_collections/fortinet/fortimanager/plugins/module_utils/fortimanager.py\", line 65, in process_workspace_lock\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload_3LmHxl/ansible_fmgr_dvm_cmd_add_device_payload.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py\", line 185, in __rpc__\nansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: Method not found\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Is this maybe an issue with Ansible using the wrong Python interpreter?  And can I force it to use a different one than 2.7?

Comment: You can set `ansible_python_interpreter` inventory variable to the path of Python you want to use.

Comment: I see I can use the -e command. Problem may be that these py files were python 2 and I have it set for python 3. I will try seeing if I can run it using the older version of python

Comment: This is an inventory variable, so you should have this in your inventory file next to the host.

Comment: https://ansible-galaxy-fortios-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html => you must use python 3 on the target. If both version are available, force python 3 with ansible_python_interpreter in your inventory, as advised in the doc linked in your error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python versions were ok.  This turned out to be an issue with the port. I switched to 443 in my host file and it started working.

```
[FMG:vars]
ansible_network_os      = fortinet.fortimanager.fortimanager
ansible_httpapi_port    = 443
ansible_httpapi_use_ssl = True
ansible_httpapi_validate_certs = False
ansible_connection = httpapi
```